# COM Passing C++ struct from C++ client to to C++ server by pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, struct, mfc

I've been researching passing a struct as a parameter from a C++ client to a C++ server using COM. I've found many examples but none that really explained it to me like I'm five nor any that really provided a firm understanding of how to do what I want, which is simply pass a C++ struct through a COM interface where both sides are C++. Should be easy, right?

I have established my struct as follows in the IDL file on server-side:

```
[
    uuid(7F0C9A48-3C41-425B-B4E6-8156B61D5355),
    version(1.0)
]
typedef struct xxxData
{
    int iWidth;
    int iHeight;
    SafeArray(short) pxxxData;
} xxxData;

// Fix for UUID DECLARATION FOR _uuidof() functionality
// From http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/error-c2787-no-guid-been-associated-158947.aspx
cpp_quote("struct __declspec(uuid(\"{7F0C9A48-3C41-425B-B4E6-8156B61D5355}\")) xxxData;")
```

Which works, so far as I can tell.

Now my client calls GetImageData which is shown as follows:

```
[id(16)] HRESULT GetImageData([in,out] VARIANT* pData);
```

Now my client call is as follows with this function:

```
VARIANT* pData = new VARIANT;
VariantInit( pData );
xxxData* data = new xxxxData;
HRESULT hr = mpCOMEvents->GetImageData(pData);
data = (FBIS_ImageData*)(pData->pvRecord);
int length = data->iWidth * data->iHeight;
```

However, length is giving me an incorrect address location. This makes me wonder if my use of pvRecord is incorrect and if I can really typecast it?

Here is my COM server side:

```
xxxData data;
//SAFEARRAY *psa;
IRecordInfo *pRI;
HRESULT hr;

/* Pass in Structure Information */
data.iHeight = 100;
data.iWidth = 100;

// Used http://vcfaq.mvps.org/com/4.htm as reference
hr = GetRecordInfoFromGuids(LIBID_xxxLib, 1, 0, 0x409, _uuidof(xxxData), &pRI);
VariantInit(pData);
pData->vt = VT_RECORD;
pData->pvRecord = &data;
pData->pRecInfo = pRI;
pRI = NULL;
```

Comment: What is pxxxData? If the server is out-of-proc then server cannot use it at all, it points to wrong memory location in server address space. Also what is pImageData member data? It seem you code sample is not completed

Comment: Sorry, I was modifying the code a little sloppily. I believe I fixed it above and also provided my latest modifications. On that note, you're right. It is out-of-proc. To avoid that, would you suggest instead of using a VARIANT* to simply output a VARIANT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some confusion here.

If you're not aiming to be automation friendly, change your IDL to:

```
[size_is=iWidth*iHeight] unsigned short* pxxxData;
```

and **don't use** SAFEARRAY API on this. For marshalling, you'll have to compile a proxy/stub DLL and register it.

If you're aiming to be automation friendly, change your IDL to:

```
SAFEARRAY(short) pxxxData;
```

and **do use** the SAFEARRAY API on this. For marshalling, you'll have to compile a typelib (optionally, embed it) and register it. This also enables early-binding (e.g. VB6, tlbimp).

This will work for languages/environments that support user-defined types. For the ones that don't (e.g. scripting languages), you'll have to use an oleautomation/dual/IDispatch-based interface instead of a struct (and implement in in the server).

---

EDIT: Based on the changes you made to your question.

You should declare the `pData` parameter as `out` only, `GetImageData` will populate it, not use it and possibly replace it. It also only requires marshaling on return, not on the call. Here's a suggestion:

```
[id(16)] HRESULT GetImageData([out] VARIANT* pData);
```

Your client code has a memory leak, it always creates an xxxData. Here's a suggestion:

```
// If pData is in-out, this is not safe, use CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(VARIANT)) instead.
// The callee may override the buffer by assuming it was CoTaskMemAlloc'ed, thus
// assuming it can CoTaskMemFree the original location and set the pointer to a new
// CoTaskMemAlloc'ed location.
// The callee may be a proxy.
// Assuming it's out only, we can provide any location with enough space for a VARIANT.
VARIANT vData; 
VariantInit( &vData );
xxxData* data; // remove memory leak
HRESULT hr = mpCOMEvents->GetImageData(&vData);
// error handling removed for clarity (I hope)
data = (xxxData*)(vData.pvRecord);
int length = data->iWidth * data->iHeight;
// ... use data ...
// Don't forget to clear the variant, or there'll be a memory leak
// It implies:
//   vData.pRecInfo->RecordDestroy(vData.pvRecord);
//     This should recursively release memory allocated in each field
//     and finally release the memory allocated for the struct itself.
//   vData.pRecInfo->Release();
VariantClear( &vData );
// don't use data past this point
```

Your server code is setting `pData->pvRecord` to point to the stack, which means that it will potentially be overwritten by a caller or some other invoked function. Here's a suggestion:

```
xxxData* data; // Changed to pointer
IRecordInfo *pRI;
HRESULT hr;

// data.iHeight = 100; // removed
// data.iWidth = 100;  // removed

hr = GetRecordInfoFromGuids(LIBID_xxxLib, 1, 0, 0x409, _uuidof(xxxData), &pRI);
// error handling removed for clarity (I hope)
VariantInit(pData);
// This will allocate memory for the struct itself
// For fields that require memory allocation, follow "normal" COM rules,
// such as using CoTaskMemAlloc for buffers, SysAllocString or similar for BSTRs,
// etc.
// For each inner (pointed to) structure, you should call RecordCreate on the
// respective IRecordInfo instance for that type.
data = (xxxData*)pRI->RecordCreate();
data->iHeight = 100; // new
data->iWidth = 100;  // new
// If pData is in-out, this will leak, use VariantClear instead.
// Assuming it's out only, use VariantInit as it points to (allocated) garbage.
VariantInit(pData);
pData->vt = VT_RECORD;
pData->pvRecord = data; // data is already a pointer
pData->pRecInfo = pRI;
pRI = NULL;
// This won't (normally) leak, the caller must call VariantClear on the out VARIANT.
// The caller may be a stub.
```

Comment: I was hoping to follow in the footsteps of http://vcfaq.mvps.org/com/4.htm where they populate a VARIANT with a struct, and then pass the VARIANT. I realize that I passed in the struct directly but I have since changed it to a VARIANT type and utilized the code from the above reference. Is it as easy as this reference makes it seem?

Comment: According to the current code in your question, you've defined a `struct` with a pointer to an `unsigned short`. First, `unsigned short` is not documented as [automation compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367129(v=vs.85).aspx); second, the standard marshaler will always (un)marshal **one** element. Even if you add `size_is`, since [this attribute in not reflected in the typelib](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236970/en-us). If you need to marshal an array using automation, you **must** use `SAFEARRAY`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the automation compatible list. I tried to find the reference to the list but couldn't. That being said, so I understand now that I will be using a SafeArray for storing of the xxxData in the struct. Going one step further, though, I just edited my code above to reflect these changes and have pretty much fixed most everything. I have a question in my comment, which is that I'm unable to access iHeight and iWidth properly after retrieving from COM.

Comment: Your server code is pointing `pData->pvRecord` to the stack! `data` should point to `CoTaskMemAlloc`ed memory, or rather, `IRecordInfo::RecordCreate`d.

Comment: You gave me exactly what I was looking for. You've been extremely helpful. Thank you so much for commenting extensively.

Comment: Cool :) Actually, just for posterity, I think it's not possible for UDTs to point to other UDTs directly, only with a `VARIANT` or a `SAFEARRAY` field. The reason is that these are the only ways a field is tagged with a proper `IRecordInfo` instance whose `RecordDestroy` knows how to free/release fields properly.

Comment: For clarification, I haven't really tested UDTs against old Visual Basic or any other early-binding automation environment. It seems possible to extract all information from a UDT even with fields that point directly to other UDTs from ITypeInfo. However, I don't know if any tool other than OLEView does that.